# ECS and SoA: can we simply get rid of the latter?

Tags: c++, game-engine, software-design

Consider the following component:

```
struct Comp {
    Whatever data;
    bool activated;
};
```

When dealing with an ECS, we have an implicit AoS model where instances are packed up together in a cache-friendly manner (hopefully at least).

Let's imagine a system that wants to iterate over all the instances of `Comp` and requires to read `data` only when `activated` is true.
In this case, when `activated` is false, data are streamed out from the main memory to the cache even if they are never used.
It can be mitigated by switching to a SoA approach. It's a matter of redefining `Comp` as it follows:

```
struct Comp {
    Whatever *data;
    bool *activated;
};
```

Well, of course, it requires also to restructure a part of the code, but let it goes. That's not the goal of the question anyway.
This time all the `activated` values are tightly packed and iteration should incur less cache misses for `Whatever` aren't streamed out to the cache if not used.

So far, so good. Pretty much a short resume, but it should give an idea of what I'm speaking about.

My guess is that in a *pure* ECS approach one can just split `Comp` in two components:

```
struct Data {
    Whatever data;
};

struct Activated {
    bool value;
};
```

Then the system can iterate over all the `Activated` components and check their `value` data members, thus get `Data` only if required. The result is (?) the same.
In other terms, as far as I can see, when dealing with an ECS we can get rid of SoA by using multiple components.

The sole drawback I can see is that you don't have any guarantee that a `Data` actually exists and is assigned to an entity when it has an `Activated` component.
Well, set aside the fact that one can enforce the constraint in debug/development mode through a few asserts, SoA doesn't really guarantee that too.
In both cases a factory method can solve the problem, so who cares?

That being said, the question is: is there any other drawback I can't see in this *pure* ECS based approach?
I mean, one can actually get rid of SoA and use more components to achieve the same result or are there cases that don't fit well with it?

Comment: You're describing essentially the same thing. Yes, you can split a structure of arrays into separate arrays of singleton structures—what's the difference?

Comment: @Alex Well, not exactly the same. The result is the same and that's why it seems to me that we can get rid of one of them. Anyway I can spot some differences easily, so we cannot say they are exactly the same. What's wrong?